# Why should i draw?

Tags: drawing

I am a 9th grade student and i am very good at drawing poses, characters, enviroments... I can even compare some of my work to 12th grade students.
Next year I am thinking of going to a programming course because i already know how to do it and i think it is the easy way out. Still i do not just want to throw all those years of drawing away but i feel i have to, and it is a skill that still pretty much defines me. I have learned to master Adobe Flash and Photoshop even with a mouse.

So, my question is, why should i even draw?

I am not trying for drawing long term but I want to fell like i have a reason to keep pushing my limits.

PS: I am from portugal so maybe the school is different from your country.

Comment: Why shouldn't you draw? This is a situation that we cannot decide for you. I'm voting to close this as primarily opinion based

Comment: I agree with Zach - this is an opinion gathering question that is not really appropriate for the Stack Exchange format. Please see the GDSE's [help](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) to see how best to ask and answer questions.

Comment: Drawing is a good, if not essential, skill to have in any technical field.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not you pursue it as a career, it is still good to have a hobby. Simply put, you should draw if you love it.

Comment: This isn't very helpful. Could you go into more detail about what you mean?

Comment: Seems to be the only valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're still young, which means you still have time to try out different skills. I would not limit yourself to one specific skill. If you love drawing and you find programming easy then pursue them both. Eventually one of them will reveal "the right" career path for you and what ever that path is will likely use lessons you learned from your time honing both skills.

Plus, there is a lot more overlap between visual arts and programming than you think. Especially when you get into the world of Games and Movies.